# In google chrome, getBoundingClientRect().x is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getboundingclientrect

I'm performing drawing operations on canvas. The best way to calculate cursor position relative to canvase top left corner is, in my opinion, usage of `.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relativeCoords = function(event) {
  var x,y;
  //This is the current screen rectangle of canvas
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  //Recalculate mouse offsets to relative offsets
  x = event.clientX - rect.x;
  y = event.clientY - rect.y;
  //Debug
  console.log("x(",x,") = event.clientX(",event.clientX,") - rect.x(",rect.x,")");
  //Return as array
  return [x,y];
}
```

I see nothing wrong with this code and it works in firefox. [Test it.](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/sj6tnfce/2/)

In google chrome however, my debug line prints this:

> x(`NaN`) = event.clientX(`166`) - rect.x(`undefined`)

What am I doing wrong? <del>Is this not according to the specifications?</del>

**Edit:** seems my code follows W3C:

### From the specs:

#### [`getBoundingClientRect()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-getboundingclientrect)

> The `getBoundingClientRect()` method, when invoked, must return the
>   result of the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Let list be the result of invoking `getClientRects()` on the same element this method was invoked on.
> 2. If the list is empty return a `DOMRect` object whose `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` members are zero.
> 3. Otherwise, return a `DOMRect` object describing the smallest rectangle that includes the first rectangle in list and all of the
>      remaining rectangles of which the height or width is not zero.

### [`DOMRect`](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/geometry/#DOMRect)

```
interface DOMRect : DOMRectReadOnly {
    inherit attribute unrestricted double x;
    inherit attribute unrestricted double y;
    inherit attribute unrestricted double width;
    inherit attribute unrestricted double height;
};
```

Comment: In Firefox, there's `x`. I told that in Firefox it works. And yes, I examined it in firebug, instead of looking in docs - that's maybe the problem.

Comment: @torazaburo [specification says there **is** `x` property](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/geometry/#DOMRect).

Comment: So this is wrong? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The object returned by `getBoundingClientRect()` may have `x` and `y` properties in some browsers, but not all. It always has `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` properties.

I recommend using the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) instead of any W3C specs when you want to know what browsers actually implement. See the [MDN docs for getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for more accurate information on this function.

So all you need to do is change your `rect.x` and `rect.y` to `rect.left` and `rect.top`.