# Infinite loop when checking if element is off screen, if not then move up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure out why this code as a while loop and as a recursive function is running infinitely.
I am checking if an element is in the viewport, if it is not, then I move its parent's top offset up until its child is out of the viewport.

HTML structure:

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

They all have set heights and widths and are display:inline-block and visible.

I've already have a jQuery psuedoclass that checks if an element is offscreen, as `.is(':offscreen'). It works fine, but I'm wondering if the original value is caching somewhere in jQuery.

Here in the code:

```
var top=1;
do{
    $('#outter').css('top', top);
    top++;  
}
while(!$('#inner').is(':offscreen'));
```

Here is the code for the offscreen psuedoclass, found on StackOverflow:

```
jQuery.expr.filters.offscreen = function(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return(
        (rect.x + rect.width) < 0  || (rect.y + rect.height) < 0 || 
        (rect.x > window.innerWidth || rect.y > window.innerHeight));
};
```

Comment: You can’t reuse an ID. The multiple `id="inner"`s are invalid.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for pointing that out, but that was just in this example code

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169534/in-google-chrome-getboundingclientrect-x-is-undefined), `getBoundingClientRect` may or may not have the `x` and `y` properties on some browsers (I've just tested it on Chrome 57 and it returned `undefined`). Use `left` as a replacement for `x` and `top` as a replacement for `y` as DOMRect always have them.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but I am still getting an infinite loop.

Comment: @wordSmith I'll say it's a far shot but try adding the `"px"` after `top` in: `$('#outter').css('top', top + "px");`!

Comment: @wordSmith and one thing I've just noticed. You're setting the top of `#outer` and checking for the offscreening of `#inner`. Could `#inner` have a fixed or absolute `position`?

Comment: @wordSmith and by the way, in order for `top` to work, the element should have either a `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute` positioning.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery won't work when you're selecting tags with duplicate IDs.

Change your inside divs `id="inner"` to `class="inner"` and change your selector to `$('.inner')`, or give your inner divs unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that was just in this example code